# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/views/index.html'

Tags: webpack, koa

It is my code:

[image]

```js
import Koa              from 'koa';
import convert          from 'koa-convert';
import nunjucksRender   from 'koa-nunjucks-render';
import nunjucks         from 'nunjucks';
import path             from 'path';
import serve            from 'koa-static';
import views            from 'koa-views';
// 路由
import homeRouter from './routers/home.router.js';

const app = new Koa();

// Must be used before any router is used
app.use(views(__dirname + 'views', {
  map: {
    html: 'nunjucks'
  }
}));
app.use(async (ctx)=>{
  await ctx.render('./index');
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port', 3000);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    index 222
  </body>
</html>
```

i build app.js with webpack  then run node build/app.js

but the serve throw Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/views/index.html'

there is my file structure

can somebody tell me why koa-views cannot find index template

Comment: That `views` folder isn't expanded Shouldn't the `index.html` file be inside it?

Comment: I stuck in same issue..cant figure out what is happening..